# turning dots in stringfromcharcode into hex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, escaping, eval, alert

I was wondering, how could i turn the dots in the function stringfromcharcode into double encoded hex code and then use it successfully? Something like this:

```
<script>alert(unescape(String%252EfromCharCode(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)))</script>
```

The working code should be able to alert hello by using double encoded hex code which in this case is %252E which is the dot double hex encoded.

Comment: Your question is unclear. That is not valid syntax.

Comment: @SLaks Yes it obviously is invalid syntax since it doesn't work. I don't understand what is unclear about my question. I'm just asking how do i use string.fromcharcode when the dot in there is double hex encoded? Could i use eval or unescape somehow? If that isn't possible, what other way could i escape the dot?

Comment: If you are asking if it's possible to write a language in invalid syntax, then the answer is obviously no. If you are not asking that, what are you asking?

Comment: I'm simply asking if it is possible to execute string.fromcharcode when the dot in that command is replaced with %252E. There must be a way.

Comment: Btw this seems like a huge [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @Esailija: He's probably trying to bypass broken XSS protection.

Comment: @SLaks and here we come with the negative comments just because you failed to solve my question. No it isn't to bypass xss protection, you're welcome.

Comment: @Tom: That's not a negative comment because I didn't understand your question; that's the only use I can think of for your question as I now understand it.

Comment: And the whole question I was trying to ask you in my comments was whether it was(or could be) a string literal.

Comment: @SLaks It's a problem with parsing urls since it isn't my website. I was just wondering how it would be possible with string.fromcharcode. To solve this problem since when a website is entered, it goes through decoding (once) thus the dot is in plain-text which is why i need double encoding.

Comment: @SLaks how could it possibly be literal when i stated i wanted an alert box alongside with the actual string.fromcharcode function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok to use eval and single quotes:

```
alert(eval(unescape(unescape('String%252EfromCharCode(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)'))))
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're actually asking how to turn `'%252E'` (a double-URL-encoded string) into `.`.

You want `decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(str))`

Comment: I know perfectly well how to do that, what i'm asking is, how do i use it on string.fromcharcode on the dot in that command when it's double hex encoded? E.g i want to alert hello when the dot in string.fromcharcode is replaced with %252E.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you asking how to make invalid syntax valid? If so, you need to change the source.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute code from a double-escaped string? If so, you need `eval`.

Comment: i want to use String%252EfromCharCode instead of String.fromCharCode to alert the hello string which in this case is (104, 101, 108, 108, 111). So the final code would use String%252EfromCharCode and successfully alert a box with hello written in it.

Comment: Something like this:`<script>eval(alert(String%252EfromCharCode(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)))</script>`.

Comment: @Tom: You can't.  The parser will reject that.